# Turn off excel workbook Data Links when inserting formulas with links

Tags: excel, hyperlink, calculation, vba

I have two workbooks - one (destination) with extensive links to the other (source). In vba when copying and then inserting new rows (with formulas containing links to the source workbook) into the destination workbook there is a significant performance hit despite have turned application.calculations = xlcalculationmanual.  It still appears that the links are being evaluated on insertion. Can I stop this and only do once at the end. The two workbooks are open at the same time.

Comment: Did you set `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` as well?

Comment: Yes - sorry should have said.